# Updating Gradle Version

Tags: macos, gradle

I am trying to update my gradle version to 4.10.2 but I'm getting an error.
I ran this command

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.10.2
```

on the root of one of my projects (in the terminal) but an error is outputted:

> Build failed with an exception. Could not determine java version from
>   '11.0.2'.

Any solutions? By the way, I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: Don't run gradle using Java 11.

Comment: How can I use an earlier version of java? I tried downloading java 8, but how do I make it the current version which I am using?

Comment: Put the Java 8 bin directory in your PATH environment variable, and not the Java 11 bin directory. Or at least, put it before the Java 11 bin directory. Run `java -version` to know the Java version you're running.

Comment: Can I not upgrade the gradle version instead?

Comment: That's what you're precisely trying to do. But you can't use the new version until you have installed it, can you?

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you access the PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Java 11 support is added in [Gradle 5.0](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html#java-11-runtime-support).

Basically the error message says, that you're trying to build against Java 11 with old version of Gradle.

If you're migrating to Java 11, then you can do the following:

1. Change JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8
2. Update Gradle to latest version, e.g.:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=5.2.1 --distribution-type all
```

3. Change JAVA_HOME to point to Java 11